# Google Map API for flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, action

Please tell me if Google Maps API is available for Flash. If it's already deprecated for Flash then which one is the best third-party or other alternative?

My goal is to make an Android Maps app using Flash Builder 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use MapQuest. It is free and works on both, Android and iOS. I used it for an app 1 month ago and it works more then fine.

http://developer.mapquest.com